# Swift adding new stack view to existing stack view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Please excuse my lingo if it is off as I am new with stack views. I have a hierarchy for my login page of several stack views inside of a stack view and am having an issue adding a new stack view to the "main" stack view. At the moment everything is working just as it should, except that when I try to drag a new stack view into the main one, it does not appear as it should, it shows up somewhere way up in the top left corner.

I am working with the size class wAny hRegular and only have constraints in a few of the stack views for maintaining the width of buttons and textfields, but as I mentioned that is working just fine, the issue only arises when I try and add a new stack view, it simply does not appear where it should. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Please let me know if there is anything else I should include here to better help you help me.

Running Xcode 7.3.1 developing for iOS 9.3

**How stack view looks within Xcode IB**

[image: How stack view looks within Xcode IB]

**How it actually shows up in the device**

[image: How it actually shows up in the device]

**The Hierarchy of my stack views**

[image: The Hierarchy of my stack views]

As you can see, the culprit is the stack view containing "Forgot Password" and "< Back"

Thanks for the help.

Comment: may i suggest watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=su03OyqPvv0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not to add stack views... what you are trying to achieve can be done with a single stack view. Delete everything and try the following:

```
- create an Icon label
- create the username text and place it below the icon label. 
- create the password text and place it below the unsername text 
- create the login button and place it below the password text 
- create the forgot password buttone and put it below login
- create the back button and put it below forgot button
```

and select all these and then in the edit menu select - embed in stack view.. This will create a stack view with all those items in a stack. Then you can play around with the properties to define how it is displayed

Comment: Yep, your solution worked just fine. Thank you for your help!